# Select row which not followed by specific one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have table with list of candidates and linked tabled with history of candidate statuses:

```
CandidateId  FirstName  LastName  
--------------------------------
1            User       One
2            User       Two
```

and

```
CandidateStatusId   CandidateId  Status         Timestamp
--------------------------------------------------------
1                   1            Assigned         ...
2                   1            Interviewed      ...
3                   1            Offer Accepted   ...

1                   2            Assigned         ...
2                   2            Interviewed      ...
3                   2            Offer Accepted   ...
4                   2            Hired            ...
5                   2            Bench            ...
6                   2            Hired            ...

1                   3            Assigned         ...
2                   3            Interviewed      ...
3                   3            Offer Accepted   ...
4                   3            Hired            ...
5                   3            Bench            ...
```

I want select candidates which has last status is 'Offer Accepted' and never before was 'Hired'. In my example only 1st user should be selected because second already hired and third was hired before (and actually on bench).

**UPD:** I prepared SQL statement which should filter users but not sure about its speed, number of users may be quite big:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.CandidatePositionStatus
WHERE CandidateId=34841
AND 'Hired' NOT IN (SELECT Status FROM dbo.CandidatePositionStatus WHERE CandidateId=34841)
```

But I do not know how to embed it in another select to provide CandidateId

**UPD2:** I prepared another query, but it is just checking whether candidate has OA status and hasn't 'HR' status, but speed of query is still opened question.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CandidateId
FROM dbo.CandidatePositionStatus
WHERE
    CandidateId IN (
        SELECT CandidateId FROM dbo.CandidatePositionStatus WHERE PositionStatusForCandidateCode='Offer Accepted' AND FirstWorkingDay IS NOT NULL
    )
    AND CandidateId NOT IN (
        SELECT CandidateId FROM dbo.CandidatePositionStatus WHERE PositionStatusForCandidateCode='Gired'
    )
```

Comment: What if the candidate id 1 have one more entry of Bench after Offer Accepted.

Comment: It is logically impossible, so this is not the case. In logic will fail with your conditions it is ok.

Comment: @AlexG.P. In you case the output should return candidate id 1 where he got the offer but not hired right?

Comment: @mr_eclair yes. But candidate may refuse offer or some other rows may appears after offer accepted. For example, candidate may rejecr previosely accepted offer. In this case it should not be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether the following query is enough. I have omitted the case of `Hire` since basic checking is for last value `Offer Accepted`.

```
select 
    CandidateId
From(
    select 
        *, 
        MAX(CandidateStatusId) over(partition by CandidateId) MaxVal
    From  
        CandidatePositionStatus
)x
where MaxVal=CandidateStatusId and [Status]='Offer Accepted'
```

Comment: Thank you for solution. It is working as expected after small adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement I wrote this.

Not tested.

```
select CandidateId
from dbo.CandidatePositionStatus
group by CandidateId
having sum(case when PositionStatusForCandidateCode = 'Offer Accepted' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
and    sum(case when PositionStatusForCandidateCode = 'Hired' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: Not working if any other row for CandidateId existing with different status. Your query returns it but should not. There are couple of statuses which cannot appears after Offer Accepted (like Bench). But there are couple of statuses wgich can.